# Unable to access the application upon updating the chrome browser(v116)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager, seleniummanager

Post updating the chrome version to 116, I am able to lauch the browser but not able to lauch the application.

image link- [image]

Below code logic, I have tried and also I have tried the setproperty but no luck.

```
if(BrowserName.contains("Chrome") || BrowserName.contains("chrome") || BrowserName.contains("Google Chrome") || BrowserName.contains("GC"))
    {
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\37029\\Documents\\Auto\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
        
        driver=WebDriverManager.chromedriver().create();
        
        ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
        options.setBrowserVersion("116");
        options.setHeadless(false);
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-in-process-stack-traces");
        options.addArguments("--disable-logging");
        options.addArguments("--log-level=3");
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    
        driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Expected:
upon lauching the browser I can also access my application on the same go.

Comment: Did you update the driver too? Those are tied to specific Chrome versions.

Comment: I have tried that one, but not worked.

Comment: This maybe the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76998277/11543023https://stackoverflow.com/a/76998277/11543023